# Msql Inner Join Query Dilemma - Need Joined Auto Increment Value

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two mysql tables that I am querying together and the query works fine. The tables are `car` and `requests`

The problem is that i need both the auto increment id's and it only gives me one.

The one it gives me is not the joined tabled.

Here is my query so far

```
SELECT * FROM `car` INNER JOIN `requests` ON `car`.`make_id` = `requests`.`make_id` WHERE `car`.`user_id` =21
```

I just need to someway get the auto increment id of the requests table.

As always stack exchange is the best place to come for answers so thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just specify your query as this and you'll get both but with different names:

```
SELECT `car`.id AS car_id, `requests`.id AS request_id, * 
FROM `car` 
INNER JOIN `requests` ON `car`.`make_id` = `requests`.`make_id` 
WHERE `car`.`user_id` =21
```

Note that you will still have an ID column which SHOULD be the requests.id, just diregard it and use car_id and request_id...

Answer (score 0):

When you have to join tables and table contains same name than it creates an ambiguous situation. So always use table name or table alias with column name Like this

```
SELECT t.column
FROM table as t  

OR

SELECT table.column
FROM table
```